# QLIKView concatenate from multiple queries

Tags: sql, load, qlikview

I want to load a query in a QVW file that but the query is returning 15 million rows so it is timing out.
I can’t really re-design the query so instead I have split what the query is returning into multiple different queries.  The query collects data from 2014 to 2020 so I have made seven copies of this query for each year from 2014 to 2020 and in each one edited the query to only pull rows from each year from 2014 to 2020. The query is called is called `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY`. So I have called the new queries `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2014`, `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2015` and so on up to `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019`

I created the queries and changed the `Qlikview` script to load each query (see script below). I just tried loading `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019` and `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2020` rather than loading them all. However I got an error `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019 table not found`
The script I have in the QVW file is this:

```
SQL SELECT *
FROM IFSAPP."GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019";

STORE GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019 into [..\QVD\GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY.qvd]; 

DROP TABLE GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019;


SQL SELECT *
FROM IFSAPP."GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2020";

STORE GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2020 into [..\QVD\GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY.qvd]; 

DROP TABLE GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2020;

EXIT SCRIPT;
```

This is what the script was before and it did not give errors but as I have described it timed out because the GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY query returns 15 million rows.

```
SQL SELECT *
FROM IFSAPP."GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY";

STORE GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY into [..\QVD\GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY.qvd]; 

DROP TABLE GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY;
```

I think I need to concatenate the queries, but I don’t know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run the first step
`SQL SELECT * FROM IFSAPP."GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019";`   and then see what the resulting table name is.

Alternatively give the query table a Qlik name by titling it with a NAME: preceding the select statement

```
QUERY_2019:
 SQL SELECT *
 FROM IFSAPP."GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY_2019";
```

as for concatenating. Qlik should auto-concatenate any tables that have identical column names so only the name of the first table loaded will exist the others will just get added to the same table

Comment: OK I am going to try the table name and see what happens.

Comment: I tried the solution suggested for 2019 and 2020 and it seems to work.